# Spring boot overrides hibernate dependency version

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

I have an issue that spring boot overrides hibernate version. I think version is taken from default managed version by spring boot 3.1.0

Here's my libs.versions.toml

```
hibernate-core = "6.2.4.Final"
hibernate-core = { module = "org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-core", version.ref = "hibernate-core" }
```

I see in my dependency list two jars of hibernate-core. First jar with verison 6.2.2.Final (Managed by spring boot, I guess) and second is 6.2.4.Final

I also tried

```
hibernate-core =  { strictly = "6.2.4.Final" }
hibernate-core = { module = "org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-core", version.ref = "hibernate-core" }
```

But it didn't help